# Calculating the length of lines in atlas mode

Tags: qgis, print-composer, expression, atlas, qgis-expression

I have created an atlas that shows polygons (parcels) with respective lines (pipes). My task now is to display the length of the pipes for each parcel.

The map looks somewhat like this (black=parcel, green=pipe):
[image]

What I already did prior to this, was splitting the lines at every intersection with the polygons and recalculate the length for each section.
My idea was to then "select" all pipes within a parcel and sum up their lengths with the expression tool. But that is the part where I'm struggling and can't find the right solution.

Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Addtionaly, would it be possible to display the pipes within the parcel shown by the atlas to change symbology (e.g. change color/get bigger)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If each pipe has the parcel ID (or any other field linking the parcel and the pipe that fall in) you may use the aggregate fonction : `aggregate(layer,aggregate,expression[,filter][,concatenator=''][,order_by])` ([ ] marks optional components)

In your case it would look like that :

```
aggregate(layer:='PipeLayerName', aggregate:='sum' ,expression:="LenghtFieldName", filter:="FieldWithParcelIDName"=@atlas_pagename)
```

If you don't have a field linking the pipe to the parcel you may try to use the `overlay_intersects` function in the filter part...